# MySQL: SELECTing Rows ORDERed BY Frequency of Value

Tags: mysql

Supposed the following table:

```
People
---------------------------
id | First Name | Last Name
```

How might I SELECT the rows ORDERed BY most frequent First Names?

Comment: Do you only need the first-names, or do you need all records, showing records with most frequent first-names first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  count(firstname) as countFn, 
  firstname 
from people 
group by firstname 
order by countFn desc
```

**edit**:id and lastname removed from select

Comment: This will not work, id and lastname can not be in the SELECT clause because they are not part of the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Martin: This is MySQL, they allow this non-standard behavior. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @Peter Thanks, didn't know that. Quote: "The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same". In that case the query in this answer would return a random id and lastname for each firstName. Brrrrr, that is scary.

Comment: in that case it doesn't make any sense to retrieve the id and lastname indeed. If you need the lastname and id in the list i recommend to use Martin's solution, if not, feel free. In the meantime, i'll remove the id and lastname from the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.*, t.count
from people p
, (select FirstName, count(1) as count
   from people
   group by FirstName) t
where p.FirstName = t.FirstName
order by t.count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to see all names sorted by the number of first names in descending order, then for Oracle this will work:

```
select n.firstname, n.lastname, g.count 
from 
people n, (select firstname, count(*) count from people group by firstname) g
where n.firstname=g.firstname
order by g.count desc
```

Not sure how this works with e.g. MySql.